# No viable overloaded '=' c++

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error message "no viable overloaded '='".
This is the code as I have it now

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    auto n=0;
    int p=0;
    cout << "enter number n:"<< endl;
    cin >> n ;
    cout << p=pow(2,n)*n! << endl; //this is where I get the error message
    cout << "the product is:" << endl;
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I have wrong?

Comment: Might be a precedence issue. And what's the full error? It won't be that vague.

Comment: Consider writing `cout << p = pow(2,n)*n!` as _two_ statements.

Comment: Additionally, you do not want to use `pow` to calculate integer powers.

Comment: What is that `!` doing there? C++ doesn't have a factorial operator.

Comment: Stop putting assignments in the middle of expressions like this. You're sacrificing readability, even if that code were correct.

Comment: Prefer not to call functions in a `cout` statement.  Use a constant temporary variable instead.

Comment: If you used a temporary, you could use bit shifting instead of calling the `pow` function.  Bit shifting is more efficient (no function calls required).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I think using `std::pow(2, n)` is *exactly* how to *express* the code! You should tell the compiler *what* to do where possible rather than *how* to do it. It is the job of the compiler (and its standard library) to make it efficient. Here is a [demo implementation](https://godbolt.org/g/28CJeo) abstracting the optimization away.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Although the compiler's job is to make it efficient, one can always provide more information to help the compiler.  Unless compilers can detect the pattern, I'm still going with bit shifting (bit shifting requires less work for the compiler).

Answer (score 8):

According to [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), operator `<<` has precedence over operator `=`.

This means

```
cout << p=pow(2,n)*n! << endl;
```

is read as

```
(cout << p)=(pow(2,n)*n! << endl);
```

which has no sense. Protect you assignment with parenthesis:

```
cout << (p=pow(2,n)*n!) << endl;
```

or better yet, split it in two statements:

```
p=pow(2,n)*factorial(n); // n! does not exist in C++.
cout << p << endl;
```

Comment: Finally, there are quite a few errors in your code snippet, some of them pointed by comments on your question. Try and fix them.